# break causing error while in valueerror loop

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm getting used to python again and I assume I have forgotten something simple, 'break' in the first number part keeps giving me a syntax error for some reason. I have tried rewriting it a few times but I guess I keep overlooking something. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number."))
    break
    except ValueError:
    print("{} is not a valid first number!".format(num1))

while True:
    try:
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number."))
    break
    except ValueError:
        print("{} is not a valid second number!".format(num2))

if num1 > num2:
    print(num1)
    break
elif num1 < num2:
    print (num2)
    break
else:
    print ("Something went wrong.")
```

Comment: indent it properly (must match the level of `num1 = ...` statement)

Comment: also do you have another upper loop you've not shared? why are you using `break` inside the `if` block?

Comment: The previous line `int(input(` is missing a closing `)`

Comment: A parenthesis is missing in `num1 = int(input("Enter first number.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use break inside if statement. Use break only inside the loop. Eg. while or for loop.